# C#, quick way to invert a nullable bool?

Tags: c#

I have a nullable bool. What is a quick way to invert it. In otherwords if value is TRUE make it FALSE, otherwise make it TRUE.

**To clarify (from the comments):**

Expected behavior is: if the nullable bool has a value, then invert, otherwise should return null.

Comment: You are way over thinking this. !myBool will give you the behavior you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "a quick way"? Quick for whom? If you mean quick for the person reading your code, it might be better to write the code in an explicit style instead of relying on language tricks.

Comment: I would hardly call negation a language trick, but a feature.

Comment: @JL, it's an obscure language feature. Judging by the comments here, a lot of people don't know about it. I didn't know about it myself. The language designers had choices about what !b means for null b. They could have thrown an exception. They could have made it evaluate to true (that's what happens in Python). That's one problem. Another problem is that if I saw "b = !b" in some code, I question whether the programmer had addressed the case where b is null. I might be then forced to consider that they hadn't. That would not be "quick".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`myBool = !myBool;`

Edit: OK, based on a refined understanding of the question (i.e. `myBool` says null if it was null), the above is the simplest answer.

Comment: @JL: It will work on nullable booleans as long as the value isn't null. In that case you need to test myBool.HasValue first.

Comment: This will return null in the case of null, not true, not sure if that's desired

Comment: I've refined the answer a touch to handle nullable types. It's not clear what the inverse of `null` would be, so I've left it up to you (i.e. I'm not entirely convinced that the inverse of null is true :)

Comment: @ChrisF: this was regarding an earlier version.

Comment: The assignment `a = !a` works just fine for nullable bool. It properly leaves the result null if a doesn't have a value. Your original answer was correct in that regard. (remainder of original comment deleted as it no longer applies)

Comment: @Scott,@Andrew -- you might want to fire up Snippet Compiler or VS and give it a test. This compiles and works just fine: `bool? a = null; a = !a;Console.WriteLine( a );`

Comment: @Adam -- please put your original answer back.  Given the comments on the question it is superior to this one.

Comment: Does `myBool ^= true` work on nullable bools? For normal bools, it yields slightly shorter and simpler bytecode (since there's no branch required), at least in Java.

Answer (score 23):

Edit, drblaise is right, `!` works just fine

```
bool? a = null;
bool? b = false;
bool? c = true;

a = !a;
b = !b;
c = !c;

Assert.AreEqual(a, null);
Assert.AreEqual(b, true);
Assert.AreEqual(c, false);
```

here is the truth table, I know, it's boring but I wanted to see how SO handled "tables"

```
   value     !value  
|---------|-----------|
|  null   |   null    |
|---------|-----------|
|  false  |   true    |
|---------|-----------|
|  true   |   false   |
|---------|-----------|
```

Comment: +1, similarly you could have a ^=true , but this is probably too obscure

Comment: This is very interesting.  I learned something new today.  Basically for **nullable primitives** a null value is like a NaN.  For instance `int? x = null` and then `x < 5` will return `false`.   However, `string? s=null` and `s.StartsWith("A")` does not return false, it throws exception. Because string is not a primitive.  However you could do `s?.StartsWith("A")` which does not throw.

Answer (score 3):

x = !(x ?? false)